# Characterization of invertible elements of a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, determinant, inverse

As invertible matrices are characterized by having non zero determinant, I was wondering if there's a similar characterization of invertible elements for more general rings with identity (perhaps something like a generalization of the determinant).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

In general, this is a very hard problem. Let me start with giving some basic examples of rings where you can characterise the units nicely:

- $F$ is a skew field, then $U(F) = F\setminus \{0\}$
- $\mathbb{Z}/n \mathbb{Z}$, then $U(\mathbb{Z}/n \mathbb{Z}) = \{a: \gcd(a,n) = 1\}$.
- Let $R$ be a commutative ring. Then $U(R[X])$ is the set of all polynomials of the form

$$a_0 + a_1 X +\dots+ a_n X^n$$

where $a_0$ is a unit in $R$ and $a_1, \dots, a_n$ are nilpotent.

- The units of the formal power series $R[[X]]$ over a commutative ring $R$ are exactly those power series

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n X^n$$

where $a_0$ is a unit of $R$.

- Generalising the previous example, in a local ring, the units are exactly those elements that are not contained in the unique maximal ideal.
- Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space. Then the units of the ring of continuous functions $C(X, \mathbb{R})$ are exactly the elements the functions that vanish nowhere on $X$.
- If $\{R_i:i \in I\}$ is a collection of rings, then
  $$U\left(\prod_{i \in I} R_i\right) = \prod_{i \in I} U(R_i)$$

But the quest for finding units is sometimes very difficult. For example, finding the units for the group ring $RG$ where $R$ is a ring and $G$ is a (finite) group is currently active research.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. The examples are really interesting and it's good to know that there is active research on the subject

Comment: @MRAA You should be able to find proofs for most all those claims in prior answers here (so you could have gained some intuition on your question by searching here).

Answer (score 2):

Here's one thing you can do in some examples. Suppose $A$ is a $k$-algebra for some field $k$, i.e. $A$ is a ring and a $k$-vector space such that the multiplication $A \times A \to A$ is $k$-bilinear. Now $A$ acts on itself by multiplication: this gives an injective ring homomorphism

$$f = a \mapsto (b \mapsto ab) : A \to \operatorname{End}_k(A).$$

You should check this if it's not obvious! Now, suppose $\dim_k A$ is finite. By choosing a $k$-basis for $A$ we get an isomorphism of $k$-vector spaces $r : A \to k^n$ (where $n$ is some natural number), and this induces a ring isomorphism $\rho : \operatorname{End}_k(A) \to M_n(k)$ such that $\rho(m)(r(a)) = r(m(a))$ for all $m \in \operatorname{End}_k(A)$ and $a \in A$. This gives us the map $\varphi := \det \circ \rho \circ f : A \to k$. Notably, if $\varphi(a) = 0$ then $f(a)$ is not invertible in $M_n(k)$ so $a$ is not invertible in $A$! The converse need not hold, but we can still determine when elements of $A$ are invertible through $\varphi$ (as follows).

If $X \in M_n(k)$ is in the image of $\rho \circ f$ we have $X = \rho(f(a))$ for some $a \in A$ and thus $$X(r(1)) = \rho(f(a))(r(1)) = r(f(a)(1)) = r(a) \implies X = \rho(f(r^{-1}(X(r(1))).$$
Once we've constructed the map $r$ by choosing a $k$-basis for $A$, the right-hand condition is easy to check for any specific matrix $X$. Therefore, we have an easy way to tell if an element of $M_n(k)$ is in the image of $\rho \circ f$.

Now, if $\varphi(a) \neq 0$, we know $\rho(f(a))$ has some matrix inverse $X \in M_n(k)$. It follows that $a$ is invertible in $A$ if and only if $X \in \operatorname{img}(\rho \circ f)$, which we now know how to check.

Of course, this isn't even close to fully general, but it's a useful technique:  not only does this give an algorithm for determining if elements of $A$ are invertible, but it gives you an algorithm for inverting those elements – if $a \in A$ is invertible then $a^{-1} = r^{-1}(\rho(f(a))^{-1}(r(1)))$! This is useful, for example, in field theory: if $A = k[x]/(p)$ for some irreducible $p \in k[x]$ our construction gives us an algorithm for computing the inverses of elements in the field $A$.

Comment: Thank you! Very interesting technique. So if I get it correctly the idea is to construct the matrix associated to a, $\rho(f(a))$, and if it is invertible as a matrix, check if the inverse X lies in the image of $\rho\circ{f}$. The preimage of X I assume would be the inverse of a we are looking for, right?

Comment: Exactly right !